# How to dynamically edit rows/columns to a Google Line chart on user action(slider/dropdown)

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

I have create a Line chart using Google Visualization API and data coming from json for the Line chart. Now i want to edit line chart on User action(can be dropdown for each point on horizontal axis) i.e. change data values that we passes to google chart i.e. edit value in "**arrayToDataTable**".

```
var lineData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Popularity', 'Time'],
[0, 0],   [1, 10],  [2, 23],  [3, 17],  [4, 18],  [5, 9],
[6, 11],  [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],
[12, 30], [13, 40]
]);
```

I already tried using Controls and Dashboards(google chart feature) that allows us to change chart like as below mentioned link:

https://jsfiddle.net/harshl22/nuff8zLc/1/

But it is only changing axis values not dataTable values like i wanted.

Is there any feature or property that will allow me to do so.

thanks in advance.

Comment: a great addition to the library would be some sort of user form controls for manipulating data. but you'll need to provide your own, then change the data manually using the methods available on the [DataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#datatable-class) (result of `arrayToDataTable`). see [`setCell`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_setCell), [`setValue`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_setValue), etc...

Comment: @WhiteHat, Thank you for the solution. I had this idea already in mind. But was hoping to get some thing that is associated with google Visualization environment only. Thanks once again for the suggestion.

Comment: don't really follow the question, when you say _can be dropdown for each point on horizontal axis_ -- how would you want the data to change when a selection is made from the _dropdown_?

Comment: @WhiteHat To be more clear, I am sharing a example of high chart that uses drag and drop functionality to change the line points on graph. http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/AyUbx/     .I am looking for something like it in google visualization.